# Conversion of String to BigDecimal format

Tags: java, string, type-conversion, bigdecimal

I have a String which is like "$1,234.00". I need to convert it into a BigDecimal value. Cannot do it utilising normal BigDecimal conversion methods as it throws NumberFormatException. Is there a way it can be achieved?

Comment: Did you try to remove the dollar sign and the “,”?

Answer (score 1):

`"$1,234.00"` is a *formatted* numeric text, so you need to parse the number using a [`NumberFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html).

In particular, you need a [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) so you can call the [`setParseBigDecimal(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setParseBigDecimal-boolean-) method, since you want a `BigDecimal` as the result, otherwise it would likely have returned a `Double`.

```java
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("¤#,##0.00", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.US));
format.setParseBigDecimal(true);
BigDecimal number = (BigDecimal) format.parse(input);
```